# C# string split - index out of bounds

Tags: c#, string

My brain is tired right now and cant come up with a simple solution to this.

```
var res = error.Split('|');
return String.Format("Name: {0} <br /> Email: {1}", res[0] , res[1]);
```

If there is no | split then it throws an error what would be a quick and graceful way to just throw in a default "No Name" or pass on it. I only care about positions [0] and [1].

Sample Data

```
Tom | huntard@123.com
Tom
Tom | huntard@123.com
Tom | huntard@123.com | texas
```

I need a redbull.

Comment: Check the length of res and insert a default if there's no res[1].

Comment: var res = (error + "|No name").Split('|');

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `ElementAtOrDefault()` extension method from the `System.Linq` namespace combined with the null-coalescing operator (`??`) for an elegant solution:

```
return String.Format("Name: {0} <br /> Email: {1}", 
    res.ElementAtOrDefault(0) ?? "No name", 
    res.ElementAtOrDefault(1) ?? "No email");
```

Answer (score 4):

How about you add an extension method to `IList<T>`:

```
public static T IndexOrDefault<T>(this IList<T> list, int index, T defaultValue)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= list.Count)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    return list[index];
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var res = error.Split('|');
return String.Format("Name: {0} <br /> Email: {1}", res[0] , res.IndexOrDefault(1, "No E-mail"));
```

Comment: You can do the same thing with the standard LINQ ElementAtOrDefault() method and the null-coalescing operator... see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Add a check on whether there is a value for the name, to validate the first item, and add an in-line check on the length of the array for the remainder.

```
var res = error.Split('|');
return String.Format("Name: {0} <br /> Email: {1}", 
                     !String.IsNullOrEmpty(res[0]) ? res[0] : "No Name", 
                     res.Length > 1 ? res[1] : "No Email");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] res = error.Split('|');

if (res.Length >= 1)       
    return String.Format("Name: {0} <br /> Email: {1}", res[0] , res[1]);

// Else return a plain message...
return "Error";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of `res` and insert a default if there's no `res[1]`

```
return String.Format("Name: {0} <br /> Email: {1}", res[0] , res.Length > 1 ? res[1] : "N/A");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just place at the top:

```
    if(error.Contains("|"))
     {return "No Name";}

var res = error.Split('|');
return String.Format("Name: {0} <br /> Email: {1}", res[0] , res[1]);
If
```

Answer (score 0):

string d ="int a f g;";

```
        string[] row = d.Split(';');
        foreach (string c in row)
        {
            string[] col = c.Split(' ');
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(col[0],col[1]);

       }//this code show string col only one length **
```

Comment: does anyone tell why first index value is comming??